# How to count the frequency of an element in every line of a file with bash

Tags: bash, count

I have a file that looks like this:

```
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
1|2|3
1|2
1|2|3|4
1|2|3|4
```

what I want to do is to count the frequency of times that a `|` appears in each line and to print a message like: *all lines have this amount except for this one that has this other amount*.

Desired output should be something like this:

```
The "|" element appears 3 times in each line except in line 3 and 4 where it appears 2 and 1 times
```

I am new at bash so I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: @choroba I've been using this code `grep -o '|' filename | wc -l` but it is counting the amount of times that a | appears in the whole file and not only in each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using awk:

```
awk -F\| '{ if (map[NF-1]!="") { map[NF-1]=map[NF-1]","NR } else { map[NF-1]=NR } } END { for (i in map) { printf  "lines %s have %s occurances of |\n",map[i],i } }' file
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F\| '{                                                         # Set the field delimiter to |
            if (map[NF-1]!="") { 
                map[NF-1]=map[NF-1]","NR                            # Create an array called map with the number of | occurrences (NF-1) as the index and line number (NR) as the value
            } 
            else { 
                map[NF-1]=NR                                         # We don't want to prefix a comma if this is the first entry in the array
            } 
            map1[NF-1]++
           } 
       END { 
             for (i in map) { 
                printf  "line(s) %s have %s occurrence(s) of |\n",map[i],i # At the end, print the contents of the array in the format required.
             }
             for (i in map1) {
                printf "%s line(s) have %s occurrence(s) of |, ",map1[i],i
             }
            printf "\n"
            }' file
```

Output:

```
line(s) 4 have 1 occurrence(s) of |
line(s) 3 have 2 occurrence(s) of |
line(s) 1,2,5,6 have 3 occurrence(s) of |
```

Comment: Do you know how can I do a counter so my output would be something like: `10 lines have 1 occurrence(s) of |, 5 lines have 3 occurrence(s) of |`

Comment: Try the amendment.

Comment: I believe I didn't really understand your last answer.

Comment: I've created another array map1 which is indexed by the number of pipes and has an incrementing value. Then I loop on map1 at the end.

Comment: I am getting this error: *awk: cmd. line:15: (FILENAME=starts_data_encoded.psv FNR=119615) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%s line(s) have %s occurrence(s) of |, 119615'
                         ^ ran out for this one*

Answer (score 0):

Using associative arrays in bash to keep track of the frequencies:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
declare -A freq lines
line=1
while read -r bars ; do
    (( length=${#bars} ))
    (( ++freq["$length"] ))
    lines[$length]+=" $line"
    (( ++line ))
done < <( cat "$@" | tr -cd '\n|')

freqs=("${!freq[@]}")
max=${freqs[0]}
for length in "${!freq[@]}" ; do
    (( ${freq[$length]} > ${freq[$max]} )) && max=$length
done

echo 'The "|" element appears '$max' times in each line'

for k in "${!freq[@]}" ; do
    [[ $k == $max ]] && continue
    echo "except in line(s)${lines[$k]} where it appears $k time(s)"
done
```